# Can I develop Drools Rules Engine on IBM Rational Software Architect?

Tags: websphere, drools, rational-rsa

I'm using IBM Rational Software Architect and I want to develop with the Drools Expert Rules Engine (http://www.jboss.org/drools). Since the IBM Rational developer suite is based off Eclipse, I am assuming I can still use Eclipse compatible plugin applications. Is this true?

I've already installed the plugin, but I am getting an error when I want to access the DRL file in the Hello World sample:

```
Unable to load dialect org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.clips.ClipsDialectConfiguration:clips:null
```

This application will be deployed on a Websphere Application Server.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the drools-clips jar. It's experimental and doesn't work at the moment, and would only be needed if you were trying to run Clips based syntax on Drools.